# Not able to register new user on pump.io api from postman

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, postman, social-networking

I am trying to hit the register API of Pump.io through postman (/main/register), But I am Unable to register, It's showing **missing required parameters**(Status code 400). Which all parameters or any other thing it requires other than a nickname, password, repeat, and email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pump.io API, but the easiest way to get the request to work in Postman is to open your developer tools in Chrome, go to the network tab, execute the request. Then right click the request and Copy as cURL.

Now go to Postman, hit the Import button, select the 'Paste raw text' tab and paste in the curl command. This gives you exactly the request as executed by Chrome and allows you to change any aspect of it.

Comment: Thanks. I got the missing detail. But how can I get the consumer key and consumer secret(dynamically) from the server(OAuth1). So, that I can pass it in Headers->Authorization to execute my routes in Postman.

Comment: You typically get these when you register the client. Not sure whether there is a way to get them dynamically.